# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources

Tags: java, ibatis

When i try to hit ibatis, i get following exception. Whatis the issue. which jar has this class. file?

7/31/10 18:48:11:917 GMT+05:30] 0000001f SystemErr     R java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources**
[7/31/10 18:48:11:917 GMT+05:30] 0000001f SystemErr     R   at **com.xxxx.pbpcs.persistence.common.DaoConfig.getDaomanager(DaoConfig.java:15)**
[7/31/10 18:48:11:917 GMT+05:30] 0000001f SystemErr     R   at **com.xxxx.pbpcs.services.common.CommonService.(CommonService.java:94)**
[7/31/10 18:48:11:917 GMT+05:30] 0000001f SystemErr     R   at **com.xxxx.pbpcs.services.common.CommonService.getService(CommonService.java:135)**
[7/31/10 18:48:11:917 GMT+05:30] 0000001f SystemErr     R   at **com.xxx.pbpcs.components.clientcreate.PickListInfoBean.ejbCreate(PickListInfoBean.java:32)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classpath is broken.  The batis jar is for some reason not on the classpath.